# Edit Distance Java

Tags: java, sorting, methods

I wrote this algorithm to calculate the sum of the number of deletion and insert (so, of the edits) to make the first string equals to the second one. But it doesn't work.

```
public static int distance (String s1, String s2) {
    return distance(s1, s2, 0, 0);
}

private static int distance(String s1, String s2, int i, int j) {
    if (i == s1.length) return j;
    if (j == s2.length) return i;
    if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(j))
        return distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j + 1);
    int rep = distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j + 1) + 1;
    int del = distance(s1, s2, i, j + 1) + 1;
    int ins = distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j) + 1;
    return Math.min(del, Math.min(ins, rep));
}
```

EDIT: Example
String 1: "casa"
String 2: "cara"
edit_distance=2 (1 deletion + 1 insert)

EDIT2: 
These are the strings that work: 
String 1: "casa", String 2: "cassa", edit_distance=1;
String 1:"pioppo", String 2: "pioppo", edit_distance=0;

These are the one which doesn't work:
String 1: "casa", String 2: "cara", edit_distance=2; (in my code=0)
String 1: "tassa", String 2: "passato", edit_distance=4; (in my code=2)

Comment: It would be nice to see a description of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Please add some examples of test strings you've used, along with their outputs. We need to be able to compare what's supposed to happen with what IS happening.  One thing that might cause an issues (i'm not somehwere i can run the code) is strings with any length start with length of 1. You're starting your recursion with 0.

Comment: what is rep? why is it okay to just skip one letter in each word at the cost of 1? seems like that immediately screws up your example and returns a 1 instead of a 2

Comment: I edited the question with some examples

Comment: Your examples do not match your code. If I just run your code, I get way different numbers. If you don't show your actual code, we can't tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the implementation is almost correct and you missed the stop conditions. They should be:

```
if (j == s2.length()) {
    return s1.length() - i;
}
if (i == s1.length()) {
    return s2.length() - j;
}
```

So the full implementation should be:

```
private static int distance(String s1, String s2, int i, int j) {
    if (j == s2.length()) {
        return s1.length() - i;
    }
    if (i == s1.length()) {
        return s2.length() - j;
    }
    if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(j))
        return distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j + 1);
    int rep = distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j + 1) + 2; // since Jim Belushi considers replacement to be worth 2.
    int del = distance(s1, s2, i, j + 1) + 1;
    int ins = distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j) + 1;
    return Math.min(del, Math.min(ins, rep));
}
```

**Update**

Here  is the result for "tassa" and "passato":

Code:

```
private static int distance(String s1, String s2, int i, int j) {
    if (j == s2.length()) {
        return s1.length() - i;
    }
    if (i == s1.length()) {
        return s2.length() - j;
    }
    if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(j))
        return distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j + 1);
    int rep = distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j + 1) + 2;
    int del = distance(s1, s2, i, j + 1) + 1;
    int ins = distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j) + 1;
    return Math.min(del, Math.min(ins, rep));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int dist = distance("tassa", "passato", 0, 0);
    System.out.println(dist);
}
```

If you run this you get:

```
4
```

Comment: testFourDistance(editdistance.EditDistanceTests): expected:<4> but was:<2>

Comment: This is my test: assertEquals(4, EditDistance.distance("tassa", "passato"));

Comment: @JimBelushi: testFourDistance(editdistance.EditDistanceTests): expected:<4> but was:<2>. And which are the values used in the test?

Comment: "tassa" and "passato"

Comment: @JimBelushi: Please check my updated response. I also get 4.

Comment: I deleted the old .class and compiled all the files again, now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That should to be what you want

If every edit of char means distance+2 (= delete + add), it also adds count of characters added/removed- but only +1, not +2

```
//get number of deletions / edits - inc 1 per each
public static void editDistance() {
    String s1 = "casa";
    String s2 = "cara";

    String longer;
    String shorter;
    if(s1.length() > s2.length()) {
        longer = s1;
        shorter = s2;
    }else {
        shorter = s1;
        longer = s2;
    }

    int edits = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < shorter.length(); i++) {
        if(shorter.charAt(i) != longer.charAt(i)) {
            edits++;
        }
    }

    edits = edits *2; //one delete, one insert you told
    edits = edits + Math.abs(s1.length() - s2.length()); //if different length then add counts of added/removed chars 

    System.out.println("edit count: " + edits);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify how to continue when you get to the end of one string but not the other, try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(distance("casa","cassa"));
}

public static int distance (String s1, String s2) {
    return distance(s1, s2, 0, 0);
}

private static int distance(String s1, String s2, int i, int j) {
    if (i == s1.length() && j==s2.length())
        return 0;
    else if(i== s1.length())
        return s2.length() - j;
    else if(j == s2.length())
        return s1.length() - i;

    if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(j))
        return distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j + 1);

    int rep = distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j + 1) + 1;
    int del = distance(s1, s2, i, j + 1) + 1;
    int ins = distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j) + 1;
    return Math.min(del, Math.min(ins, rep));
}
```

output

```
1
```

Note: the first `if` is not necessary, just make the code more understandable... remove it in your impl

Comment: @JimBelushi are you sure? works for me, can you provide the input?

Comment: String s1 = "casa";
String s2 = "cassa"; assertEquals(1, EditDistance.distance(s1, s2));

Comment: @JimBelushi works, maybe something wrong with your testing syntax or something...

Comment: Can you try it on “tassa” and “passato”? The output should be 4

Comment: @JimBelushi That should be 3: one replacement 't' to 'p' and 2 inserts 'to'.

Comment: @JimBelushi, no the output should be 3 replace `p` with `t` and add `to` to the end

Comment: No, because you need to delete the final "t" and "o" and change the first "t" with a "p" (to do it you need 1 delete and 1 insert)

Comment: @JimBelushi do you have different costs for delete and replace operation? otherwise I don't understand how 2 deletions and 1 replace sum up to 4

Comment: I know, but in my project I need to count the operation of replacement as two

Comment: @JimBelushi Ok, then just add 2 to that operation. Please check my updated answer below.

Comment: I added +2 instead of +1 to the rep variabile but it doesn’t works

Comment: @JimBelushi Did you check the code below in my answer?

Comment: @JimBelushi works, gives 4, again check your syntax, the code below is the same code as this post... but without the unnecessary if, give him the points!

Answer (score 0):

Two easy changes and your code works:

First:

```
    if (i == s1.length()) return s2.length() - j;
    if (j == s2.length()) return s1.length() - i;
```

instead of

```
    if (i == s1.length()) return j;
    if (j == s2.length()) return i;
```

Next:

```
    int rep = distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j + 1) + 2;
```

The 2 at the end is important here. If rep means replace, it is a remove AND an insert. Making it two operations, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

It works with me:

```
private static int distance(String s1, String s2, int i, int j) {
    if (i == s1.length() && j == s2.length()) {
        return 0;
    } else if (i == s1.length()) {
        return s2.length() - j;
    } else if (j == s2.length()) {
        return s1.length() - i;
    }

    if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(j)) {
        return distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j + 1);
    }

    // int rep = distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j + 1) + 1;
    int del = distance(s1, s2, i, j + 1) + 1;
    int ins = distance(s1, s2, i + 1, j) + 1;
    //  return Math.min(del, Math.min(ins, rep));
    return Math.min(del, ins);
}
```

There is the test and it works too:

```
/**
 * Test of distanceRec method, of class EditDistance.
 */
@Test
public void testDistanceRec() {
    System.out.println("distanceRec");
    String s1 = "passato";
    String s2 = "tassa";
    int expResult = 4;
    int result = EditDistance.distanceRec(s1, s2);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
    // Review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
    //fail("The test case is a prototype.");
}
```

In this app you can only use two operations: insert and delete, no other operatios like replace or match.
Text of exercise:

> Assume that the operations available are only two: deletion and insertion of a character. Examples:
>   - "casa" and "cassa" have edit distance equal to 1 (1 cancellation);
>   - "casa" and "cara" have edit distance equal to 2 (1 cancellation + 1 insertion);
>   - "tax" and "past" have edit distance equal to 4 (3 cancellations + 1 insertion);
>   - "poplar" and "poplar" have edit distance of 0.