# Java Code optimization - Fastest list to search and remove?

Tags: java, string, collections, substring, large-data

so I've been working on a task. I have two giant strings, both consist of the same characters just scrambled. The task is to find the lowest possible number of changes you can make to turn the first string in the other one, while 1 change = switching neighbour chars in the string. I found a solution that works just fine but there is a problem. It works under 5 seconds only for input of about 100 000 char Strings. I need to make it work for up to 1000 000 char. I tried ArrayList, LinkedList, regular arrays, substrings and different variations of the algorythm, this one is the best so far I came up with but I'm out of ideas. Any help? Is there a faster collection I can use? Maybe the algoryth is wrong here?

"jas" ArrayList is the first string converted into a list
"mal" is the other one. "steps" is the output

```
int steps=0;
int index=0;
while(jas.size()>1) {
    if(jas.get(0)!=mal.get(index)) {
        int distance = jas.indexOf(mal.get(index));         
        jas.remove(distance);
        steps+=distance;                
    } else {
          jas.remove(0);
      }
    index++;        
}       
System.out.println(steps);
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ <- try here

Comment: what about edit distance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49900588/edit-distance-java/49901073?noredirect=1#comment86818312_49901073

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit off topic here (you should go to codereview) but idea I got is to use something already implemented in Java like:
listToSort.sort(Comparator.comparing(listWithOrder::indexOf));
Go to functions the function and look at them and you can either take them out and create your own based on that and put a counting there or inspire by it.

I believe that whatever is implemented there is probably very fast.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I do not have enough rep to comment, but I agree 100%. :D